# How to set customize location of mqclient.ini using mqseries.net dll?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I want to set the mqclient.ini location to custom one rather than c:/program files(x86) /IBM/webspheremq.

I am using mqseries.net with c#.
Websphere MQ version 7.5.0.0

I have read somewhere to use MQCLNTCF environment variable. But I am not sure how to use it? I am not able to find variable under MQEnvironment object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read through this link: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016850_.htm

Comment: I have already referred the link. Not useful.  I am not getting how to make it work with c#..

Comment: Can you explain why you need the mqclient.ini to be in a different location? Are you setting some parameters in mqclient.ini that you the MQ .NET client to pickup? Show us some sample code if you have?

Comment: I need to use TCP connect timeout settings from. Ini file... The reason to store this file at diff location is i want to make. Ini file location customized.

Comment: @Shashi, option 2 is not working. I have put .ini under website directory but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know what a Windows Environment Variable is?

In a Windows batch file, do the following:

```
set MQCLNTCF=C:\some\path
```

Or make it global by going to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Setting -> Environment Variables

then set the variable as either a User or System environment variable.

Finally, did you read point #2 of that link?  That is the easiest way of handling the mqclient.ini file.

Comment: I read all the points shared in the link.  It's default path and i want to use. Ini file from diff location

Comment: Can't i use some code in c#? I want to make. Ini location customizable for admin user

Comment: Fyi,  i am using mqclient from the server

Comment: You seem to be all over the place.  The simplest solution is #2 - put the mqclient.ini in the application's working directory or just go with (#1) a Windows environment variable that the Admin controls.

Comment: Thx for the comment. I can see option 1 is easy but I have to set some variables on server (PROD server -high risk). option 2 is already there but I can't customize the location then. I want to set it using C# code only so that it can be manageable.
can we set it using c# code using amqmdnet.dll ??
can we set TCP timeout other than this way(using code only)?

Comment: option 2 is not working.  If I put the .ini file in my website directory (runs under IIS on my windows server 2003) it is not working. What is the use of the second option then?